# Donut Polygon remove in Building SHP exported from Autocad

Tags: donut-polygons

I have created Buildings footprint in Autocad and exported to SHP which is having so many Donut polygons. Is there any way to clip polygons in SHP files (Batch)

I have found one script on net but it is creating issue as it is clipping overlapping errors too.

Modified Script:
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import os ,sys

## System Variables:

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"Current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

## Local Variables:

Vendor = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
donutLayerUnion = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
idField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Donut_Processed = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

## Union analysis

arcpy.Union_analysis ("Vendor","donutLayerUnion","ALL","","GAPS")

## Delete Identical analysis

arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management ("donutLayerUnion","Shape;Shape_Area","","")

## Copy Feature Class

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion ("donutLayerUnion","C:/Temp","Donut_Processed.shp",where_clause="",field_mapping="",config_keyword="")

## Delete Layers

arcpy.Delete_management("c:\temp\Donut_Processed.shp", data_type="ShapeFile")

## Delete layer from active frame

for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "donutLayerUnion", df):
        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
pythonaddins.MessageBox ('Process Done..','Kailash',0)

Comment: You want to Fill-in the donut holes?

Comment: Yes, I want to clip and fill the hole created by donut